# Mostrar dato de Firebase a un TextView Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, textview

tengo una duda espero y me ayuden quiero mostrar un dato de firebase en un textview en Android pero la verdad no tengo idea como hacerlo, el dato en especifico esta como "Valor[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacerlo hace lo siguiente

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.child("Persona").child("Valor").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int valor = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(valor);
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("Fallo la lectura: " + databaseError.getCode());
      }
    });
```

Primero creamos la referencia a donde esta el valor, y luego vamos y buscamos ese valor, lo guardamos en una variable de tipo entera int y luego lo ponemos en el `TextView` con `setText`, usamos `String.valueOf` ya que es un entero y `setText` necesita pasarle un String.

Cada vez que ese valor se modifique, tu `TextView` se va a modificar con ese valor en tiempo real.

Nota: recuerda que las reglas de Firebase deciden quien tiene acceso a los datos , por lo que si no te funciona o no te lee, no es el codigo sino tus reglas , puedes usar las siguientes para debuguear por el momento y luego en produccion las cambias por reglas mas seguras

Solo debug. Si no vas a usar autenticacion y no importa quien lee o escribe la base de datos, puedes dejarlas asi

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```

> Recuerda que addValueEventListener... como otros listeners en Firebase
>   son asyncronos, esto quiere decir que trabajan en segundo plano
>   pidiendo los datos y cuando los tienen , recien hacen la accion que se
>   encuentra dentro de `onDataChange` por lo que poner el `setText` fuera
>   de `onDataChange` no pondria nada ya que no puede acceder a ese valor
>   antes de ser solicitado.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, me funcionó un saludo

Comment: Ningun problema jorge, cualquier otra consulta solo pregunta, un saludo